# Why is the my $.ajax( ) data not passing to my .cfc

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I'm updating a variable based on the value selected from a drop-down list, and it just isn't working.

On this site I have another CFC which is working fine, however this one is just downright refusing to post the data.

**jQuery**

```
$('.accessLevel').change(function() {
    var theValue = $('.accessLevel').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "setLevel.cfc",
        data: {
            method: "theLevel",
            alevel: theValue
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
            alert('YES');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('NO');
        }
    });    
 })
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="accessLevel" class="accessLevel">
   <option value="">Select an Access Level</option>
   <option value="1">Level One</option>
   <option value="2">Level Two</option>
   <option value="3">Level Three</option>
</select>
```

**CFC**

```
<cfcomponent>
  <cffunction name="theLevel" access="remote" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="alevel" type="any" required="yes">
    <cfset SESSION.accessLevel = argument.alevel>
    <cfreturn />
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The variable `theValue` is being populated, it just won't pass through to the CFC and I have no idea why! The error I'm getting is this..

```
Element ALEVEL is undefined in ARGUMENT.
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your error, but if the function does not return anything you can just omit the `returntype` (or use `returntype="void"`) and skip the `<cfreturn />`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regards to that error, the scope name is `arguments` (with an s), not `argument`.  Try changing that and see if you get passed that error.

```
 <cfset SESSION.accessLevel = arguments.alevel>
```

Comment: You don't need the pound signs around Arguments.ALevel FYI.

Comment: Right, ColdFusion will take it either way.  I removed them from my sample.  Thanks!